# Keep hover color despite changed backcolor for a button in Visual Studio 2010

Tags: winforms, visual-studio-2010

I would like to change the color of buttons in Visual Studio 2010. But I like the default style with the blue hover color and the impression of depth.

When I write `Button.BackColor = Color.LightCoral`, the hover color and depth impression disappear. How can I fix this?

I am on Windows 7, Visual Studio 2010, using WinForms, not WPF.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution I chose is to keep the visual style of the button pressed.

The clever way to do so it actually not to use buttons, but check boxes with button appearance, like explained [here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/winforms/thread/b267fcd6-1e13-4828-9c6c-0e03d9a4d5ab).